# Vlookup on fulfilment of certain condition

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-query

Within my Google sheet I need to find a value in a specific range (say A15:A45) when the row value in another column (Say Column D) exceeds a specific cell value (Say C20). How do I write the syntax?

I did try using Vlookup and If combination. Also tried using query. However I think I am making some mistake in the arguments. either I get an error or I do not get any outcome.

Comment: did you try anything?

Comment: Yes. I did try using Vlookup and If combination. Also tried using query. However I think I am making some mistake in the arguments. either I get an error or I do not get any outcome.

Comment: Please add some data sample, you may add sample sheet, or paste mock-up data like in this Q: https://stackoverflow.com/q/48152363/5372400  . Adding details to your Q will help others to answer it, and learn by your case.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming C20 and ColumnD are Numeric (other than a label) then perhaps:

```
=query(A:D,"select A where D > "&C20&"")
```

VLOOKUP would not be suitable as this does not "look to its left" and an INDEX/MATCH combination would not be suitable for multiple results.