# How to use an IF to allow me to select between the views?

Tags: google-sheets

I am currently creating a dashboard in Google Sheets.

- In cell `A2`, one can select from two views (let's say "test" and "test2").
- In `A5` they can pick a starting date and in `A8` one can fill in the end day.
- In cells `A10:C17` I have some mock-up data (see below).

Now what I want is to display the data between two dates and based on the views (in the table called selector. Users can select test and test2). I am able to use Filter() to filter the dates, however, I am unable to select a view. Thus I can only use it for the dates, not for the views.

This is the formula that allows me to filter the dates:

`=arrayformula(ifs($A$2="test";1)*FILTER(A11:C17;A11:A17>=A5;A11:A17<=A8))`

Anyone any idea on how to use an IF (or any other function that might work) to allow me to select between the views?

Mock-up data:

```
Selector
Test



Start date      
01-01-2018  



End date        
03-01-2018  



Date        Users   Pageviews
04-01-2018    350         400
03-01-2018    300         350
02-01-2018    250         300
01-01-2018    200         250
31-12-2017    150         200
30-12-2017    100         150
29-12-2017     50         100
```

If you want you can view the spreadsheet here:  https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-1vRjwsm49p48sP2dZXWjdMacw9vLe0GoADLKc_J4E2Sggo5hDpp2a_2zpCsZM4jlW21CfLrG_TSthhV7/pubhtml
In A10:C17 you can see the data I want to show for test and in A20:A27 you can see the data I want to show for test2.

Comment: What do you mean "between the views"? If I select the full date range and "test2" what should I expect to see?

Answer (score 0):

[Sample File](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1rksV1-Us_l1UlTVlSkMpjgrsXnBO4Xc4W03y9Uo2yNo/edit#gid=0)

`=if(
    A2="test", 
    formula_1, 
    if (A2="test2", formula_2, "Other")
    )`

In the formula above, `if` a user selects:

- "test", then the result is `formula_1`,
- "test2", then the result is `formula_2`,
- else the word `"Other"` will appear

Replace:

1. `formula_1` with `FILTER(A11:C17;A11:A17>=A5;A11:A17<=A8)`
2. `formula_2` with a formula for the second view.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. However this only returns the date. I would also like it to return the data entries in the table.

Comment: `FILTER(A11:C17;A11:A17>=A5;A11:A17<=A8)` will return 3 columns of data (A, B, C) between 2 dates, to return the whole data, you need {A11:C17}.

Comment: Yes the filter part, without if, will deliver 3 columns of data. However if I put the FILTER as part of the IF it will only return a date.

Comment: It worked for me, please see my [sample file](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1rksV1-Us_l1UlTVlSkMpjgrsXnBO4Xc4W03y9Uo2yNo/edit?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 0):

This works for a combined "view" drop down. If you want to separate the view options to get a side-by-side comparison, that should be no problem.

**Filter**

```
=IF(A2="test",FILTER(A11:C,A11:A>=A5,A11:A<=A8),IF(A2="test2",FILTER(A11:C,A11:A>=B5,A11:A<=B8),"Sorry. No matches found"))
```

**Selected dates minus 1 year**

```
=DATE(YEAR(A5)-1,MONTH(A5),DAY(A5))
```

See this [Google Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1vfBXhs8Zr_PqKRqM6eOffcBYl4OxqV2HbRL0sIU-M_g/edit?usp=sharing)

The dates ranges in the drop downs are just `data validation` based on the spreadsheet data.